# why the three dots on toolbar are not showing

Tags: android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I'm trying to add a custom toolbar to my android app, but I can't get the three dots to display in the main xml file. I have remove the default bar in the manifest file, and added a toolbar in main_activity.xml. also created a menu.xml file showing the drop down menu. But the neither the 3 dots or the app name is displaying in main_activity.xml. little help thanks
main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.droidscanner.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="http://pctechtips.org"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/read_network"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Scan Net"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nodelist">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

menu.xml in res/menu/menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_ping"
        android:title="Ping"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_connections"
        android:title="Connections"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_nslookup"
        android:title="NSlookup"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

code added to onCreate method MainActivity.xml

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Comment: I followed this tutorial but it is not working https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html